# Read out "Display" of "Appearance and personalization"

Tags: c#, windows-7, controlpanel

I want to read out the value of the "Display"-Setting out of the "Appearance and personalization" in the controlpanel of Windows7 with a C#-App , because prior Startup the app has to check that the value is set in 100% and inform the user if this is not the case.

Here is what control panel I mean:
http://maketecheasier.com/change-icon-size-and-display-settings-in-windows-7/2010/01/12

Thank you in advance!

I tried:

- (Code-Example from [How to get Windows Display settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings) did not work, its always 96)
- SystemInformation.IconSize (?)
- Maybe it is a value of the system metrics - what what value? (http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.SystemMetric)

Answer (score 0):

You are after the two "dpi" settings in Windows, one in the horizontal direction, and one in the vertical direction. It is very common that `dpiX` and `dpiY` will be the same:

```
float dpiX, dpiY;
Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
```

**Note**: Most programs are poorly written, and [do not handle high-dpi display setting](http://rawr.codeplex.com/discussions/40864)s properly. Because of this, starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft lies to any application that does not ***specifically*** declare that it correctly supports high-dpi displays. Applications are told that the display is still set to the (legacy default) 96dpi. Windows then uses the video card to resize your application to make it larger:

[image]

You opt out of *high-dpi scaling* by adding an entry to your application's `manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <assemblyIdentity 
            version="1.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            name="client"
            type="win32"
    /> 

    <description>My Super Cool Application</description> 

    <!-- We are high-dpi aware on Windows Vista -->
    <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>

    <!-- We were designed and tested on Windows 7 -->
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
            <!--supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/ -->
            <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>

    <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization -->
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>

</assembly>
```