# Capture image error in window 8

Tags: c#, screen-capture

I have a class that I'm using to capture Screen

```
class ScreenCapture
{
    public Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // get the hDC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
        // get the size
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
        // restore selection
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        // free up the Bitmap object
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        return img;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureScreen();
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resize a bitmap image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmp">Bitmap File</param>
    /// <param name="nWidth">new width</param>
    /// <param name="nHeight">new height</param>
    /// <returns>return a new bitmap image after resizing</returns>

    public Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int nWidth, int nHeight)
    {
        Bitmap resultBmp = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)resultBmp))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
        }
        return resultBmp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class GDI32
    {

        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
            int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
            int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
            int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

    }
}
```

And then I declare a variable and capture screen and save it to an image

```
   private ScreenCapture m_handleCapture = new ScreenCapture();
   m_handleCapture.CaptureScreenToFile("C:\\temp2.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
```

The image is not full, right and bottom regions are cropped. I don't know why. The code was running on window 8, 64 bit.

Comment: What is the DPI? It is possible that the machine this doesn't work on isn't 96dpi & some conversion may be necessary to the width/height

Comment: We have a lot of computers. Some of them when capturing the picture is cut off but these others are normal. I will try what you suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jewelnguyen8: I just ran it on mine (Windows 8, 64-bit, 120 dpi) and it did a full resolution (1920x1080) capture fine.

Comment: @jaytre You're right. I changed my DPI to the smallest. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change DPI to the smallest. It works.

Here taught me how to change:
http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10807/~/how-do-i-change-the-dpi-of-my-display-on-my-computer-with-windows-7%3F

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to convert the width\height to 96dpi for the image.

```
double dpiX, dpiY;
double width, height;

int dpi96Width = (int)(width/dpiX * 96);
int dpi96Height = (int)(height/dpiY * 96);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681.aspx) for more info on DPI-aware applications.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is applying this answer. It give you full information about how to get DPI, and some problem about it.

[How to get Windows Display settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings)

Answer (score 0):

To receive the physical (opposed to the logical) size of the target `HWND`, mark your application as High DPI aware, or use [`LogicalToPhysicalPointForPerMonitorDPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn384110(v=vs.85).aspx) to translate the result from `GetWindowRect`.

To [mark your application as High DPI aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx#declaring_dpi_awareness), add the following to your manifest:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

See [MSDN: Accessing Window Trees while System DPI–aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx#walking_window_trees_while_ystem_dpi-aware) for details on High DPI support.