# How to get screen item current magnified percent (windows Desktop setting) in C#

Tags: c#, windows

In Windows (including windows 7 or 8), we can set the size of item/icon when displaying by these steps:
Right click My Computer->Screen Resolution-->Make text and other items are larger and smaller (the blue hyperlink below). In default mode, there are 3 options: 100%, 125%, 150%.

Now I have to extract this setting (one of three options) in C# code. How can I do this task?

Comment: issue was discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings

Comment: thank you. I've solved that problem