# Java - Get Windows Scale percent

Tags: java, scaling, jna, display

I need to figure out what the scaling is set to.  This answer at [Windows scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586883/windows-scaling) gives code in c/c++/c#, but I need it in Java and would much prefer to not have to do JNI.  Is there a way to use JNA to get that information?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to do it:

```
GraphicsConfiguration asdf = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

AffineTransform asfd2 = asdf.getDefaultTransform();

double scaleX = asfd2.getScaleX();
double scaleY = asfd2.getScaleY();
```

Forgive the bad variable names. And instead of defaults, you may want to account for multiple displays. But that shows how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a savior.
However one thing I would like to point out. 
In Java 8. Value is always coming as 1.0
Working fine in open jdk 11.