# Size dimensions distortion when moving my project to another device

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working with NetBeans and when testing my application on different devices, the panels and some objects of my Frame change their position or size, which makes it unusable in cases due to the disappearance of buttons, this also happened to me in C++, but never I knew how to solve it, does anyone know how to do it?

It should be noted that the main panel has an Absolute Layout, I don't know if that affects it.

Comment: Usually images are not the best way to add clarification in StackOverflow, but in this case, they would be pretty useful. Take a screenshot of your app in different devices to properly see what you mean. I'm not good at UI design/programming to help you out, but I can suspect that `Absolute Layout` is part of the problem.

Comment: Note also that many PC have screen scaling which can cause a lot of issues with swing applications, especially on 4k+ screens. Take a look here and see if this makes a difference [How do I run Java apps upscaled on a high-DPI display?](https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display) also see here for several ways to work out the scaling so that you can display your UI accordingly [Windows scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586883/windows-scaling) For more help please include some more information (screenshots) and some short sample code