# Permanently change the font of my application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How can I change the font of my project in a way that anyone who downloads the app sees it with the font that I choose?

I'm using C#, Microsoft Visual Studio Code, Winforms.

I keep searching but all that I can find is a tutorial on how to install the font on my own computer.

Comment: Does the font is standard or very specific to your OS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: [How to properly render an embedded Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64512339/7444103) -- [PrivateFontCollection & / Or Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231407/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the font of all controls in a form (.NET Framework). See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426291/change-the-font-size-of-all-controls-in-the-application-win-forms).

But, if you are using .NET Core (.NET 6 or later) you can:

In project file inside `<PropertyGroup>` add:

```
<ApplicationDefaultFont>Curlz MT, 18pt</ApplicationDefaultFont>
```

You can also call `Application.SetDefaultFont()` directly in your `Main()` method as shown here:

```
static void Main()
{
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

    Application.SetDefaultFont(new Font(new FontFamily("Curlz MT"), 18f));

    Application.Run(new AirQualityForm());
}
```

Comment: But that still requires that font to be installed for all other users (computers)

Comment: If he wants to Add a Font programmatically, there is posts with this question. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986744/how-to-install-a-font-programmatically-c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a custom font working.

(Important: In this example I dragged "FiraCode-SemiBold.ttf" into the root of my project, then I right clicked it in visual studio and set the property: "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" (copy always will work too))

```html
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
    pfc.AddFontFile("FiraCode-SemiBold.ttf");
    FontFamily fontFamily = pfc.Families[0];
    float fontSize = 8.25f;
    FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
    GraphicsUnit graphicsUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
    byte gdiCharSet = 1;

    Application.VisualStyleState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
    Application.SetDefaultFont(new Font(fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, graphicsUnit, gdiCharSet));

    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```