# Simple way of calculating window size based on percentage of screen size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a C# VSTO Excel add-in, and there are some features where I will launch a WPF window after clicking on a ribbon button.

I have this window where I set the height to be 80% of the screen's height, and the width to be 60% of the screen's width. However, this will not work if a user sets his DPI to be more than 100%, my WPF window will grow outside of his screen viewable area.

So, after doing some Googling, I found out that I have to consider the scaling factor into my calculation. I'm referring to [How to get Windows Display settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings) to get the scaling factor.

My question, is there a simpler way to do this? In Javascript/CSS, we can just use 80vh and 60vw, but so far I do not see such helpful feature in C#.

I find it ridiculous that I have to write code to take care of these scenarios, instead of just having a code to calculate the window size I want relative to the screen size.

Here's my code right now:

```
    var scaleFactor = GetScalingFactor();
    var handle = (IntPtr) Application.Hwnd;
    var screen = Screen.FromHandle(handle);
    var winHeight = screen.WorkingArea.Height * scaleFactor * 0.8;
    var winWidth = screen.WorkingArea.Width * scaleFactor * 0.6;

    private static float GetScalingFactor()
    {
        var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
        var desktop = g.GetHdc();
        var xDpi = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.LOGPIXELSX);
        return 96 / (float) xDpi;
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
    public enum DeviceCap
    {
        VERTRES = 10,
        DESKTOPVERTRES = 117,
        /// <summary>
        /// Logical pixels inch in X
        /// </summary>
        LOGPIXELSX = 88,
        /// <summary>
        /// Logical pixels inch in Y
        /// </summary>
        LOGPIXELSY = 90

        // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetDeviceCaps.html
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of your question is that you want this to be simple.
You could work out the device independent pixels as a multiplier on your particular monitor and apply that.

I have my settings at 125% and this gives me .8:

```
        Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(fe)
            .CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
        double dpiFactor = 1 / m.M11;
```

Another way to do this would be to maximise your window initially.
Once rendered, you know this is going to be just under the size of your monitor and you can get actualwidth and actualheight of the window.
Then calculate *.8 and *.6 to give you roughly the size you want.
I assume this is good enough for your purposes and nobody is taking a ruler to their monitor on this one. There's a subtle difference due to window chrome and maximised which will vary depending on OS. Hopefully that is academic though.

If you don't like the window jumping about then you could make this into an animation feature.
Make the window transparent and style none initially.
Show the content in a centered grid.
Animate the height and width up to the size you calculate.
Then set the size of the window.
Don't animate the window height and width. (It'll do first one then the other.)

Comment: What is "fe"? I've tried using that method, but I'm not sure what to put for the parameter of FromVisual.

Comment: It's any frameworkelement, I pass a window in where I use that code.