# How do i read the screen scaling factor (100%,125%,...) from display settings in Visual studio (c#)

Tags: c#, screen, scale

I have looked at every similar question and none work for me. I am programming a winForm that will show me the screen factor. I have tryed reading from Registry (doesnt work) i have tryed using DLL "gdi32.dll" , that works but only on Win10 not on Win7. 
I Have also tryed :

```
float dpiX, dpiY;
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
    dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
}
```

but it doesnt work also.
I know that this question is repeated but all the answers that were in the previous questions didnt help, so thats why i am opening a new one.
So, can someone help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Windows Display settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings)

Comment: Why do you need this information?  Is it just for diagnostics, or are you trying to re-implement scaling in your app?

Comment: @SᴇM I wrote in my comment that this question is repeated. so i know it is a duplicate, but in the original question i didnt get the right answer. There are a lot of answers but non of them work. SO thats why i opened another one.

Comment: @Neil i am running a WinForm in Labview. Labview has a button that is covered by the WinForm (like a Guide) and i have fixed coordinates where the button is. IF the user uses a different scaling factor (125%,...) the button has different coordinates so.

Comment: @NemanjaVidačković What you mean under _"it doesn't work"_?

Comment: @SᴇM The result from dpiX and dpiY is always 96 . when i scale the screen to 125% or 150% i also get 96 so thats not realy helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetDpiForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdpiforwindow) with a Manifest.

```
uint nDPI = GetDpiForWindow(this.Handle);
```

I get =>

```
        100% : 96
        125% : 120
        150% : 144
        175% : 168
```

Declaration =>

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint GetDpiForWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
```

Manifest =>

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true/PM</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
     </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me also, i always get 96. thanks

Comment: @Nemanja Vidačković with a Manifest to force dpiAwareness ? (I tested in C# and C++ on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Without manifest file: You must first set SetProcessDPIAware() right after the program starts. It sets the process-default DPI awareness to system-DPI awareness. Otherwise it will always return 100%.

```
internal static class Program
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
        
        static void Main()
        {
            SetProcessDPIAware(); //sets the process-default DPI awareness to system-DPI
            int scale = GetDpiScaleFactor();
            Console.WriteLine(scale);
        }
        
        static int GetDpiScaleFactor()
        {
            const int _DEFAULT_DPI = 96;
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)); //A Graphics object is needed for native DPI detection.
            return (int)(gr.DpiX / _DEFAULT_DPI * 100); //In percentages, as shown in Windows
        }
    }
}
```