# How do I set the window position to the left/right side of the screen

Tags: selenium-webdriver, position, screen

I am executing a test using Selenium, that is executed on 3 browsers in parallel.
I want to position the windows the next way: left side, right side and bottom,
So basically i'm looking for a command on Selenium that does the same effect as (start btn+left btn...)

I have tried using these commands:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800,650));
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
```

But the problem is that I need to enter the exact coordinates and when executing the test on different screens it might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to get the screen resolution: [Get and Set Screen Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082610/get-and-set-screen-resolution)

For example, if you want your window to be in the center of the monitor, and the monitor is let's say 1000px, then put the 1000px in a variable and set the window position to 1000px divided by 2, instead of 500 hard coded.