# Moving a page across screen in wpf

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I am new to WPF and just starting to get used to it,
I want to move a page across the screen when I load it. The Code I using for that currently is :

```
<Storyboard>
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1920,0,0,0" />
        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="SummaryPageName"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"
            AutoReverse="False">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

While this works fine for me, what I want is to not use hard values(1920) in value field of

```
<SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1920,0,0,0" />
```

Is there anyway to do that without specifying this value, so that it will work with other resolutions as well.

Thank you

Comment: I recommand you to bind the Value to your viewmodel properties.
Then you will be able to get your screen resolution, I think you must have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082610/get-and-set-screen-resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the KeyFrame value with code behind.
You should assign resource name to the storyboard resource to be found by code behind.

```
[XAML]
<Storyboard x:Key="myStoryboard">
```

Get the Storyboard object instance by referring x:Key.

```
[C#]
private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard s = this.Resources["myStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
    SplineThicknessKeyFrame k = (s.Children[0] as ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames).KeyFrames[0] as SplineThicknessKeyFrame;
    k.Value = new Thickness(e.NewSize.Width,0,0,0);
}
```

Also you may use data binding to change keyframe value. If you need to change a lot of keyframe resources, you should use data binding. Otherwise changing value manually is easy to prepare.